# VPN Log Files Windows

Tags: windows, vpn, logging

I have a friend who is quitting their job. 
He is owed overtime, but the workplace has been casual about recording hours.
He regularly signs out a work laptop, and will work from home via VPN.

Is there a way to retrieve log files for this person, despite the fact they use a different computer for the majority of the time that he could copy as an aid to his claim for overtime hours?

Normally, if it was a everyday computer, I would check some common log files, eventvwr.msi etc.

Thoughts?

Comment: This is better asked at SuperUser - I flagged for migration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are relevant log files in `\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles` that may help. There is also system information available from the Event Viewer (`Run > eventvwr.exe` OR `Control Panel > Admin Tools > Event Viewer`) and look for System logs.

However, both these locations could be empty depending on local settings.

One can configure Windows firewall to log VPN connections but that is not a default. Check `Control Panel > Windows Firewall > [Advanced tab]`, the default location is `C:\WINDOWS\pfirewall.log` for the log file.

Specific applications used may have preserved log data. If you know the IP address connected to you could do a general search for files containing that IP address (but that wouldn't find compressed logs or non-ASCII log data).

Answer (score 13):

Expanding on @pbhj's answer, I successfully found logs following [these instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20151030124631/https://it.umn.edu/advanced-instructions-l2tp-native-vpn), summarized here:

> 1. Navigate through the Start menu to get to the event Viewer: Start >
>    Control Panels > Administrative Tools > Event Viewer.
> 2. In the Actions
>    pane, select Create Custom View or Filter Current Customer View.
> 3. Select the event severities (e.g., Critical, Warning, Error,
>    Information, etc.) listed under the Event level option.
> 4. Click the
>    Event sources pull-down menu and select the event sources that you
>    would like to see, for example: VPN Client - vpnagent, vpnui; DHCP -
>    DHCP-Client; Native VPN - RasMan, RasClient, Remote Access.
> 5. Save the
>    filter to Custom View.
> 6. Select the log event in the event browser page
>    (top).
> 7. Event Properties in the middle pane has the log details for an
>    event.  Double-click an event to bring up a new Event Properties window
>    in addition to the Event Properties pane.

I used specifically "RasClient", and found this Error level log in the Custom view:

> CoId={53F1C7C6-B011-4453-B2D5-C0F82ED8E590}: The user {domain}{username} dialed
> a connection named {target VPN connection} which has failed. The error code
> returned on failure is 789.

(Note I was looking for logs because my VPN errored, not because I wanted to see my VPN history as in OP's question)

Answer (score 1):

I found these event IDs:

- Connect Event: RasMan 20267
- Disconnect Event: RasMan 20268
- General Details: "RasClient" logging

You can use several tools to filter for these events.

## Try FullEventLogView

Try [Nirsoft's fulleventlogview.exe](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/full_event_log_view.html). It will show connect/disconnect events.

1. Open `Advanced Options`
2. OPTIONAL: `Show only events from the last...` 1 Days (or however many you want)
3. `Show only the specified providers (comma-delimited list, wildcard allowed)`: RasClient,RasMan

[image: FullEventLogView]

## Or try Custom View

Do to the same thing inside the regular Windows Event Viewer do this.

1. Save this text here as `eventvwr.custom-view.RAS.xml`:

```xml
<ViewerConfig>
    <QueryConfig>
        <QueryParams>
            <Simple>
                <Channel>Application,System</Channel>
                <RelativeTimeInfo>0</RelativeTimeInfo>
                <Source>RasClient,Rasman</Source>
                <BySource>True</BySource>
            </Simple>
        </QueryParams>
        <QueryNode>
            <Name>RAS</Name>
            <QueryList>
                <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
                    <Select Path="Application">*[System[Provider[@Name='RasClient' or @Name='Rasman']]]</Select>
                    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='RasClient' or @Name='Rasman']]]</Select>
                </Query>
            </QueryList>
        </QueryNode>
    </QueryConfig>
</ViewerConfig>
```

2. Start => Run... => eventvwr.msc <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Event Viewer (Local) => Custom Views => right-click => Import Custom View...