# Troubleshooting L2TP/IPSec on Windows Server 2019 with PowerShell

Tags: vpn, powershell, ipsec

The problem which I've got is that a Windows Server 2019 VM hosted in the cloud crashes exactly after it shows that a L2TP/IPSec connection is successfully established.

According to the VPN server (StrongSwan), the connection has been indeed established.

```
localhost charon: 16[IKE] CHILD_SA L2TP-PSK{93} established with SPIs cedc6269_i c2c04b84_o and TS
```

I've checked online documentation to [enable the VPN log](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/325034/how-to-troubleshoot-a-microsoft-l2tp-ipsec-virtual-private-network-cli) but can't find it in the 2019 edition; neither can I see any useful information in the [Event Viewer](https://superuser.com/questions/897029/vpn-log-files-windows).

So my questions are:

- how can I enable/identify VPN event log and what has happened as the system crashed?
- how can I script the VPN configuration with PowerShell?

Comment: This is not really a PowerShell issue or PowerShell code question, soooo, why the PowerShell tag?

Comment: @postanote indeed this is a PowerShell question.

Comment: But you are not showing the PowerShell code you are trying. Thus, not really enough to help you here. Are you saying you are trying to troubleshoot this using PowerShell?  Yet, you seem to be asking, what event log info should one be looking for, hence my comment. One, of course, can look at evt stuff without automation efforts, but looking at a bunch of filtered stuff from evt files, I get that. Yet, one can troubleshoot without automation.